# Best Practice for transferring images to an Android phone?

Tags: file-system, images

I switched from iOS to Android, and wish to transfer my pictures.

Where on the filesystem should I put the pictures? I first thought `/DCIM/camera`, but that's the directory for pictures shot with the phone.

`/media` and `/Pictures` seem to be appropriate, too.
I just want to set up everything in the best possibly way. I also want the pictures to be in different folders e.g. holidays, work, etc...

I have a Nexus 4 phone, if you need that to help me.

Comment: You could basically store them anywhere. As long as the directory does not contain a `.nomedia` file, the media scanner will find and catalogue them, so you apps (like e.g. gallery) will find and show them. On my phones, there was a `Photo` directory on the sdcard. The Nexus 4 not having a card slot, you probably could simply create such a folder on its internal sdcard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please feel free to use a folder structure which suits you. It's better if you create a seperate folder for pictures, inside *media* folder or on the primary folder itself. (where the folders such as DCIM and media are located.)

As your title asks, there are no hard and fast methods to transfer data to your phone. Standard file transfer safety measures apply.

About keeping seperate folders, do NOT use too many folders which might result in slowing down the phone. No matter where you put the images, the album app finds them. (Just make sure that you don't copy them in to folders that you do not know of)

Have fun with android.

Answer (score 1):

I would place the images in the /Pictures folder, but there is no real 'best practice' as far as I know. That is the fun thing about Android, you can place the pictures wherever you want, you'll be able the access them in every picture application. So you place them where you would think they belong, if you need them later.

You can make the necessary folders and normally Android will organize them according to the folder where it's in. At least that is the case on my phone, but I have another phone (HTC One X, so maybe HTC added this feature).

Btw, `I switched from iOS to android` deserves a +1 :-)